# (index):13 Uncaught ReferenceError: LoginUser is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: html, angular

```html
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
<input #user matInput placeholder="username" type="text" name = "username" id="username">
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
<input #pass matInput placeholder="password" type="password" name="password" id="password">
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
<button onclick="LoginUser(user,pass)" class ="btn btn-primary" type ="submit" mat-raised-button >Click me!</button>
</div>
```

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  LoginUser(user:HTMLInputElement,pass:HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log(user.value);
    console.log(pass.value);
   }


}
```

I'm using Angular material design 
I'm not able to print the username and password data on console

Comment: `LoginUser` is not defined. Where do you define it?

Comment: `onclick=...` should be `(click)=...` Angular uses the same events as regular javascript but without the 'on'. To bind an event with Angular, you have to use the parentheses.